# Javascript check if any of the values exist on array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, array-filter

The CMS I am using allows my to expose my entries as json

```
 "name": "James Green",
 "department": [
            {
              "value": "office",
            },
            {
              "value": "accounts",
    }
]
```

For the filter I am creating I need to check if the either of the values is equal to my selected value.

At the moment the following returns the correct result but only filtering the first object of the array.

```
  return this.people.filter(person =>
     {
        return person.department[0].value === 'office';
     }

)
```

At present people can only be in a maximum of 2 departments but it could change. How do I check all the objects in the array for my value.

Edit:

Tried some but it just returns true.

```
  return this.people.some(person =>
     {
      person.department == 'office';
     });
    }
```

Comment: Just update your check to check for all the values instead of just one.

Comment: You most likely want to get rid of the arrow expression function and have an actual function, which will allow you to use a loop and check all values.

Comment: Use [`some()`](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=javascript+some&ia=web).

Comment: @pie3636 You can easily do a loop in a fat arrow function just as you would in a named function.

Comment: @pie3636 That's not the case. The filter function is exactly what the OP wants as far as I can see. The problem is that he only checks on `department[0]` instead of all departments.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I thought arrow functions where expressions only. I'm not sure how you'd add a loop to one.

Comment: @pie3636 You add a loop exactly the same way as you do anywhere else. In this particular case, `some()` is better than an explicit loop, though.

Comment: @Psi I believe you misread my comment. I didn't say to get rid of the filter function, only to flesh out the expression arrow function inside into a non-expression function where they could use a loop.

Comment: @pie3636 The notation makes no difference here, whether an anonymous function or just using the lambda notation is exactly the same. Won't help with the problem to just change the notation.

Comment: @pie3636 If you have a bare expression `() => expression` then it is the returned result of the fat arrow. If you have a body in braces `() => { statements }`, you can write any arbitrary code you wish. Just remember to explicitly `return` the result.

Comment: @pie3636 In this particular case, the OP can get the correct result with an expression using `Array.prototype.some()`.